# Script works under "click" event but not alone (Backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a canvas element attached to the body of the document under the View (separate from it). I would like to append that canvas element to a div inside the View. It works on click, but when I put it inside the render function, it doesn't. This is how the code looks like:

NOT WORKING:

```
render : function() {
    var that = this;
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
        $('canvas').appendTo('.container3');

    return this;
}
```

WORKING:

```
events : {
 'click .qgaz': 'blabla'
},

blabla : function() {
     $('canvas').appendTo('.container3');

}
```

Why is this happening and how can I make it work on its own when the page loads?

Edit - here goes the complete view:

```
window.printView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName : 'div',
className : 'print-menu-view',
initialize : function() {
    var that = this;
    // tu wybierz template z templates/main.tpl
    this.testowaZmienna = "test";
    this.template = _.template($("#print-view").html());
    console.log(this);
    return this;
},

events : {

},

render : function() {
    var that = this;
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
        $('canvas').appendTo('.container3');
        console.log(this);

    return this;
}
});
```

Comment: Double check the value of `this`.  Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: console log the value of this in render and initailize and check whether both are same or not

Comment: I checked and they are exactly the same.

Comment: can u show the complete view?

Comment: I edited the question and added the complete view.

Comment: Can you provide some demo

Comment: I tried putting it in jsFiddle but it's not working, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: if '.container3' is inside your view then would you not want to do $('canvas').appendTo('.container3', this.$el);

Comment: Than you all for suggestions, in the end I made it work by creating a function under **render**: `addElement : function(){$('canvas').appendTo('.container3');}` and calling it in scripts.js inside the **print** function that loads the view.

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to access the element by the `.container3` selector, it isn't part of the document tree yet, but it's already contained in the cached jQuery object `$el`:

http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el

Finding `.container3` in the cached element

```
this.$el('.container3').append(...)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Vote up because the fact that it's not the part of the document yet was exactly the issue. I can't accept the answer though as I managed to find another solution before (stated in the comments above).

Comment: That's fine, if you think that this solution will help other users with the same problem, consider accepting it. There are couple of workarounds to achieve the same thing, but this is how you should do it in Backbone.

Comment: I'll take a look at it and see if it works in my case when I have a moment, and if it does I will accept it for the future generations :)